# Ruby on Rails - how do I create a url to pass a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made this namespace and route:

namespace :api do
   resource :create_kpi,  :except => [:edit, :destroy]
 end

the controller looks like this:

```
class Api::CreateKpiController < ApplicationController
  def create
    temp = Kpi.new(params[:data])  

    puts "temp: "
    puts temp.inspect    
  end
end
```

and I would like to do something like this:

```
POST    http://127.0.0.1:my_port/api/create_kpi?data="some stuff"
```

but I am not sure how to construct the url with the setup I have. How should my url look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be passing data in query parametr for the POST request, so your url should look like HOST:PORT/api/create_kpi and POST DATA should have data="some stuff"

here is a curl example

```
curl -i http://HOST:PORT/api/create_kpi -F data="some stuff"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your routes entry should create a helper called `api_create_kpi_path` or something like that which you use in your links. You can just pass that route helper params you want added as query params, so `api_create_kpi_path(:data => "some stuff")`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you have a controller and you want to know what to put in the view?

In that case, since you are posting data take a look at the [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) and [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), rails will construct everything for you to submit a post.

A very useful resource to getting started on things like is the [definitive guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms).